# Customize KMSI from checkbox to yes or no buttons as a separate user journey

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I working with enabling the Keep Me Signed In setting for Local Account sign-ins.

Currently, the Technical profile is set-up as follows.

How would I set up a separate Technical profile to capture the response from the user whether the user is either opiting in or out of KMSI? Also, how to change the UI/UX behavior to buttons of Yes or No, instead of a single checkbox?

Claims Provider:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
    <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
        <Metadata>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">true</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="recaptchaResponse" />
        </OutputClaims>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-VerifyRecaptcha" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-SignUpOrEditProfile" />
        </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
        <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
        <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
        </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
        <Metadata>
        <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.enableRememberMe">True</Item>
        </Metadata>
    </TechnicalProfile>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
        <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

And, the ClaimsProvider is called in the User Journey as follows:

```xml
<UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
        <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
            <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
            </ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
```

How would I branch out of this user journey to collect the value of selection for Keep Me Signed In from the user in a customized button selection (from yes or no)?

I have gone through lot of samples from the community and couldn't seem to find any example of this type of interaction.

Answer (score 2):

### Styling the checkbox

The only real way to make this a radio button is to use [custom UI templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy), and have CSS hide the original checkbox and inject the Yes/No radio boxes with JavaScript to check/uncheck the hidden checkbox when the user clicks either of the radio buttons.

It is not natively supported to change the KMSI element type within the policy.

---

### User's KMSI response

To capture the response from the user whether the user is either opting in or out of KMSI, you can add an output claim to the sign-in technical profile.

You will need to create a claim to hold the value:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="UserKmsiChoice">
  <DisplayName>Indicates whether the user selects the me signed-in option</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>Readonly</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

Update your output claims for `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` to populate the new claim using the [Claim Resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#context):

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.enableRememberMe">True</Item>
    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserKmsiChoice" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Context:KMSI}" />
  </OutputClaims>     
</TechnicalProfile>
```

This claim can then be used in the rest of your user journey as normal.

Comment: If I may ask an additional question. The original question `<UserJourneys>`, the technical profile "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" is called in the Orchestration Step 1. Would it be possible to separate the collection of the KMSI Metadata setting into a sub-journey that gets called after successful sign-in?

Comment: Just like, when you click the forgot password, you are provided with a sub-journey and then you are rejoined back to the sign-in flow. Similarly, when the user provides the email and password and clicks Sign In, upon successful validation of the credentials by the existing journey, will then move the user to a new sub-journey where you provide the custom UI with the radio buttons to opt in or out of KMSI. Upon selection, then you validate and redirect to the application URL.

Comment: I don't believe this would be possible. In "normal" orchestration steps with user interaction steps are using a [content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#datauri) with a `selfasserted` data uri whereas for KMSI you need to use a `unifiedssp` data uri which is specifically for signing in the user.